# Using Python Virtual Environments with Terminator

Tags: python, virtualenv, terminator

With [Terminator](https://launchpad.net/terminator), a user can define *layouts* within the configuration file. With these layouts, the user can set a command to be executed at start-up. So, for example, one could create a layout in which a terminal automatically executed `ls` like this (note the `bash` command to avoid the terminal closing):

```
command = "ls; bash"
```

Now, how can I make Terminator load a Python Virtual Environment instead? Keeping, of course, the bash console active with the environment loaded.

### Note

The trivial way:

`command = "workon my_env; bash"`

or its `source my_env/bin/activate` equivalent (without using `virtualenvwrapper`), wont work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick is to do everything with just "one" command: `bash`. Taking advantage of its `-i` option (interactive) and using a custom `--rcfile` in which `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set to whatever we want to execute. The result would be like this:

```
command = "bash --rcfile <(cat ${HOME}/.bashrc; echo 'export PROMPT_COMMAND="workon my_env; unset PROMPT_COMMAND"') -i"
```

### Explanation

- We execute `bash` in interactive (`-i`) mode.
- We execute commands from a custom command file (`--rcfile`) instead of `.bashrc`.
- This file is created with the contents of `.bashrc` plus one more command.
- This extra command exports `PROMPT_COMMAND` with a value of "whatever we want to execute". In this case: `workon my_env`.
- The `PROMPT_COMMAND` is unset just after it is executed the first time to avoid multiple executions after each interaction with the shell.

One could easily extend the custom command just editing the part `workon my_env`. So, for example, if you want to automatically execute `ls` appart from loading the Virtual Environment, you would write `workon my_env; ls` instead.

Comment: unfortunately that does not work for me, I get error `/bin/bash: =: command not found
/bin/bash: line 0: unset: ´PROMPT_COMMAND') -i': not a valid identifier`

Comment: This does finally work for me as well. Any chance to actually also cancel that command? mine runs forever.